# Scraping Noise from front right wheel on bumpy roads

Tags: ford, noise

Background: 2003 Ford Taurus SE, middle of a very harsh winter here in New England (We've had 100 inches of snow so far this season).

-Today when driving to work I noticed that there seemed to be some type of scraping noise coming from I believe the front right wheel region. It sounded a lot like my mudguards/splashguards whatever you call them, and I figured maybe a lot of ice had built up on them and they were bogged down and lowered, thus hitting the road more easily. However when I arrived at my destination they seemed fine. Everything from what I saw looked fine. It seems like it won't make the noise on a bump but rather like a noise that is a sudden uphill or downhill if you can somewhat understand what I mean. It's not making this noise when turning and it's not making a constant noise. It just sounds like something is scraping against the ground but when I looked under my car with a flashlight nothing seemed extra low to the ground. What could this be?

Comment: Did you look for buildup _inside_ the wheel wells?

Comment: With someone bouncing the front of the vehicle, observe to insure that nothing touches when the suspension is compressed. Also look for rub marks(usually shiny metal).